# autowired dependency not getting mocked while executing test case with junit and mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am using Junit4 and Mockito for test cases, in the following code `dbprop.getProperty("config")` is throwing a `NullPointerException` because dbProp is null. Please help me out why it was not mocked?

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
    @Autowired
    protected DBproperties dbprop;
}

public class SampleClass extends BaseClass {
    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    valdiateOrder(String input) {
        String config = dbprop.getProperty("config");
    }
}

public class TestSampleClass {
    @InjectMocks
    SampleClass sampleClass;

    @Mock
    private OrderService orderService;

    @Test
    public void testValidateOrder() {
        DBproperties dbprop = mock(DBproperties .class);
        when(dbprop.getProperty("config")).thenReturn("xxxx");
        assertNotNull(SampleClass.valdiateOrder("xxx"));
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you load your context before autowiring in your test classes

Answer (score 2):

Your `dbprop` mock has not been injected into `sampleClass`, you need to add:

```
@Mock
private DBproperties dbprop;
```

Then remove the `dbprop` mock creation from your test method:

```
@Test
public void testValidateOrder() {
    // DBproperties dbprop = mock(DBproperties .class); <-- removed
    when(dbprop.getProperty("config")).thenReturn("xxxx");
    assertNotNull(SampleClass.valdiateOrder("xxx"));
}
```

Next, to ensure mocks are injected when using the `@InjectMocks` annotations you need to either add the following runner:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestSampleClass {
...
```

Or call the following in a `@Before` method:

```
@Before 
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

See the [MockitoAnnotations](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html) and [MockitoJUnitRunner](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html) JavaDocs for more information on the two approaches.

Comment: Jon, tried as you said,but still getting null pointer Exception.

Comment: @seenu That's strange, I tried your code and it failed with the NPE. Then I added `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and it passed (i.e. injected the mocks). Can you add the stack-trace to the question please? Thanks.

Comment: @seenu I just thought, you need to remove the mock from the test method, see my updated answer.

Comment: getting null pointer exception at dbprop.BaseClass is abstract class does it work injecting mocks?

Comment: @seenu What version of Mockito are you using? If it's less than `1.9`, try upgrading. Reason being, there's a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=229) in 1.8.5 that may explain the what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate your Object with @Mock, so its look like this

@Mock
DBproperties dbProperties;@Before public void init(){ MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}